# How do I find errors in a XML file?

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

Sometimes when I'm trying to run my code, the Eclipse console says:

> Error in an XML file: aborting build.

That means that I have a mistake in my main XML file. Is there any way to find my mistake without making guesses and erasing some XML code in order to see where the problem is? Something like validation of my XML file! Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[XML Tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XML%20Tools/External%20libs/ext_libs.zip/download), a plugin for [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) allows you to check if the XML syntax is broken and tells you on what line the error is.

To install the XML tools plugin, [download the plugin zip file](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XML%20Tools/External%20libs/ext_libs.zip/download), and extract the contents to where you have installed Notepad++ (such as C:\Program Files\Notepad++). Then restart Notepad++, open the XML file you wish to check, click on the "Plugins" menu at the top, select "XML Tools" and click on "Check XML syntax now."

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for your answers!!i m writing xml for android developement.will this be helpful ???

Comment: Well, if you have the XML file on your computer, you can use notepad++ to correct it, if it has any errors. However, if you are using Android to create the XML or want to correct the XML using Android, I wouldn't know anything about that.

Answer (score 3):

You could even open it in firefox, and if it is malformed it will show you where the error lies.

Comment: Intriguing!  I'm looking for misplaced apostrophes and other symbols; it doesn't seem like Firefox catches those.

Comment: @Scott, what do you mean with misplaced apostrophes ? (*an example*) .. Does it make the document invalid ? (*if so it should be caught by FF*)

Comment: Well, it sort of makes XML invalid as far as Android goes.  Here's an example:

<string name="aint">ain't</string>

will parse fine as far as Firefox is concerned. But the ' without a preceding backslash may or may not be cause problems with your xml file (and may or may not cause warnings in Eclipse). Those errors can cause R.java to not regenerate (or even disappear), and the resulting errors can be very frustrating as the source (your XML file) is not the obvious culprit.

Comment: Did some more research.  You can the complete explanation at:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

Answer (score 0):

Can't say for sure if it is same issue but I have on occasion Run my application with an xml file as the active window and that creates an abort build. Make sure your not Running an xml file.

Answer (score 0):

> XML Tools, a plugin for Notepad++ allows you to check if the XML syntax is broken *and tells you on what line the error is*.

I think that Notepad++ reports *the first line after the error(s) at which Notepad++ knows there must be an error earlier*.

I have just used Notepad++ and XML Tools to investigate a file which turned out to have about 30 "single bit flipped" errors.  For example, "text:p" appeared as "text:q"; "table-cell" appeared as "table:cdll" and ">" appeared as "=" etc.

Initially I thought that the error must be in the matched tags section immediately preceding the reported line.  However, with so many errors I was looking for problems a hundred or two hundred lines above the reported error line and well above the immediately preceding matched tags section.

I reasoned that if an end ">" had been converted to "=" then Notepad++ would be reading much that followed as free text.

I found XML Copy Editor much easier to use as it found each line with an error.  I needed to pretty print first using Notepad++.